# Django Template Second Form Input Triggering Wrong View

Tags: django

Trying to have two forms on one page and have a user select a create input or load input. Should be pretty straight forward. Doesn't seem to work. Anytime I click select a person and click load, it evaluates the first URL for Create. Can someone please point out what I'm missing? I'm sure it's something simple.

Views:

```
def Create(request):
    print('Create View')

def Load(request):
    print('Load View')
```

URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Index, name='index'),
    path('person/', views.Create, name='Create'),
    path('person/', views.Load, name='Load'),
```

Template:

```
{% block body_main %}
<form action={% url 'Create' %} method='POST'>
<h2>Name</h2>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form1 }}
<input class="btn btn-success" name="form1btn" value="Submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
<br>
<form action={% url 'Load' %} method='POST'>
<h2>Select Existing Name</h2>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form2 }}
<input class="btn btn-success" name="form2btn" value="Submit" type="submit"/>
<form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: As far as I understood django flow, url is matched with your urlpatterns. Since both URLs are same, it matches the very first one you have defined which is Create View. If you want two forms, you can create one single view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem (also mentioned in point 3 in [Django URL docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request):

```
 path('person/', views.Create, name='Create'),
 path('person/', views.Load, name='Load'),
```

Everytime django URL matcher gets here, it will usually hit `Create` first and return.

> Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL, matching against path_info.

So it will always return the `Create` view.

To solve this problem I suggest creating 3 separate URLs that are more readable:

```
 path('person/new', views.Create, name='Create'),
 path('person/load', views.Load, name='Load'),
```